# Resizing parent widget to fit child post 'Transform' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm using `Transforms` in Flutter to create a scrolling carousel for selecting from various options.

This uses standard elements such as `ListView.builder`, which all works fine, aside from the fact that the parent widget of the Transform doesn't scale down to fit the content as seen here:

[image: notice the gaps around the perspective transforms]
Here's the code used to generate the 'card' (there was actually a Card in there, but I've stripped it out in an attempt to get everything to scale correctly):

```
    return Align(
      child: Transform(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        transform: mat,
        child: Container(
          height: 220,
          color: color,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
          child: Text(
            offset.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Even if I remove the 'height' parameter of the Container (so everything scales to fit the 'Text' widget), the boxes containing the `Transform` widgets still have the gaps around them.

Flutter doesn't seem to have any documentation to show how to re-scale the parent if the object within is transformed - anyone here knows or has any idea of a workaround?

**EDIT:** The widget returned from this is used within a `build` widget in a Stateful widget. The stack is Column > Container > ListView.builder.

If I remove the Transform, the Containers fit together as I'd like - it seems that performing a perspective transform on the Container 'shrinks' it's content (in this case, the color - check the linked screen grab), but doesn't re-scale the Container itself, which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: what is the parent widget, where you are returning this whole code?

Comment: Thanks @Chinky for adding the image. I couldn't due to my current rating.

Comment: @BigRedSwitch it's not related to rating, just simply put a '**!**' before the image link :D

Comment: @Chinky Sight - I tried. Denied! D-:

Comment: did you ever find a solution? 
ran into exactly the same problem and do not understand why "setState" does not make Listview.builder recalculate the height of the transformed tile

Answer (score 2):

I have a tricky solution for this: addPostFrameCallback + overlay.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class ChildSizeWidget extends HookWidget {
  final Widget Function(BuildContext context, Widget child, Size size) builder;
  final Widget child;
  final GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();
  OverlayEntry _overlay;

  ChildSizeWidget({ this.child, this.builder });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = useState<Size>(null);

    useEffect(() {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timestamp) {
        _overlay = OverlayEntry(
          builder: (context) => Opacity(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                child: child,
                key: _key,
              ),
            ),
            opacity: 0.0,
          ),
        );

        Overlay.of(context).insert(_overlay);

        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timestamp) {
          size.value = _key.currentContext.size;
          _overlay.remove();
        });
      });
      return () => null;
    }, [child]);

    if (size == null || size.value == null) {
      return child;
    } else {
      return builder(context, child, size.value);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

class HomeView extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final change = useState<bool>(false);
    final normal = Container(
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
      height: 200.0,
      width: 200.0,
    );
    final big = Container(
      color: Colors.redAccent,
      height: 300.0,
      width: 200.0,
    );

    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: ChildSizeWidget(
            child: change.value ? big : normal,
            builder: (context, child, size) => AnimatedContainer(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(child: child),
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
              height: size.height,
            ),
          ),
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('Toggle child'),
          onPressed: () => change.value = !change.value,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I have a menu with several options, they have different height and with the help of the animations this is ok, it's working really nice for me.

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Align, as much as I can see in your code, there is no property set or used, to align anything. So try removing Align widget around Transform.
Because according to the documentation, Transform is such a widget that tries to be the same size as their children. So that would satisfy your requirement.

For more info check out this documentation: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints

I hope it helps!

Comment: The align is just to prevent the parent widgets being scaled across the whole screen. It's not really relevant to the problem here. I've already tried removing it - made no difference. See 'Edit' above for more details.